# Помогите сделать метод POST с JSON! Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

я работаю с телеграмм-ботом, но это не столь важно.
Сразу скажу, что `message.text` - данные, что ввел пользователь.

Я работаю с API owo.vc и для получения сокращенной ссылки нужно сделать метод POST.

Но я столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу сделать JSON для отправления данных, он должен выглядеть так:

```
{
  "link": "https://example.org",
  "generator": "owo",
  "preventScrape": true,
  "owoify": false
}
```

И мне нужно отправить такой запрос, но я не помню абсолютно, как сделать JSON словарь, хотя метод POST помню. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться библиотекой [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), конкретно функцией [`post`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests). Если передать данные в параметре `json`, то они будут автоматически преобразованы, и к запросу добавится заголовок `Content-Type: application/json`.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests

url = 'https://owo.vc/generate'
payload = {
  "link": "https://example.org",
  "generator": "owo",
  "preventScrape": True,
  "owoify": False,
}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)

result = r.json().get('result')
print(result)
```

***stdout:***

```py
owo.owo.vc/uwU.uvU_uvU.OvO
```

Comment: Скопировал себе в shell ваш код, получил ошибку `No module named 'requests'`. Надо установить модуль ?

Comment: `pip3 install requests`. Спасибо, сэр. Вы очень добры, сэр. Ничего страшного, сэр. Вы можете обращаться ко мне, если вам ещё что-нибудь будет нужно, сэр. Всенепременно. До новых встреч :)

Comment: `uwu.owo.vc/UwU-Uwu/uvU_oVo`